# C++ Delete a Custom Widget From QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have been searching everywhere for this question but no one seem to have an answer. I added a QProgressWidget within a QListWidget using  setItemWidget. I am currently trying to delete the progress bar with a push of a button.

I intended for the list widget to look like this

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGZga.png)

This is the code I've used to insert a name and a qprogress bar

```
//append qstring
ui->budget_list_2->addItem(expense_name);
//append qprogress bar
ui->budget_list_2->addItem(tmp);
ui->budget_list_2->setItemWidget(tmp, bar);
```

This is the code I used to remove both items

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui->budget_list_2->count(); i++){
        if(ui->budget_list_2->item(i)->text() == remove){
            tmp = ui->budget_list_2->takeItem(i);
            delete tmp;
            tmp = ui->budget_list_2->takeItem(i+1);
            delete tmp;
            //delete prog_bars.take(remove);
            break;
        }
    }
```

But when I go to remove both the qstring item and the progress bar, I get this

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m3Bs.png)

Since I inserted both items right after another, I assumed that their position was i and i+1 but I am clearly I was wrong. Can anyone tell me how to delete a widget inserted within a QListWidget?

Comment: well, what happens to the index of the progress bar once you remove the text? try reusing i or delete them in reverse order ...

Comment: To clarify, you want to remove both the progress bar and the QString? If that is the case, is it possible to change your current implementation such that budget_list_2 only contains the bar and the qstring? If you are able to make the modification, remove them will become as simple as looping over the list and removing everything from it.

Comment: @Thomas Oh I see, that make a lot of sense. From my understanding what you're saying is that after takeItem(i), i would automatically be the position of the progress bar and all I need to do is do takeItem(i) and delete twice correct?

Comment: @Lucas yes, that's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I explained the code in the comments inside it. The problem is that after you remove `i-th item`, `(i+1)-th item` will be `i-th item` and `(i+2)-th` item will be `(i+1)-th item`. That's why you have removed 2 `QString` in your code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <ui->budget_list_2->count(); i++){
    if (ui->budget_list_2->item(i)->text() == remove)
    {           
        //remove (i+1)-th item first
        auto barItem = ui->budget_list_2->item(i + 1);
        if (barItem)
        {
            //delete bar widget
            auto bar = (QProgressBar*)ui->budget_list_2->itemWidget(barItem);
            if (bar)
            {
                bar->deleteLater();
            }

            //remove and delete bar item
            delete ui->budget_list_2->takeItem(i + 1);
        }

        //remove string from ui->budget_list_2
        auto strItem = ui->budget_list_2->takeItem(i);
        if (strItem)
        {
            delete strItem;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```